# IE CSS hover loses focus when over img

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on making some drop-down menus. Our designer prescribed a gap between the mega menu and the rollover item. Normally, no problem at all. I just dropped a transparent div tag there in the middle, and we're good to go, right? Nope. Well, everything (FireFox, Chrome) BUT IE works. The problem is the image that is below the gap between the menus. If I remove the image or turn the extension div white, all is well. But I would like to have the best of both worlds. Is this possible? Is there more information that you need to be of assistance?

Thanks,

JMax

HTML:

```
<ul id="navMenu">
        <li class="navItem">
            <a href="#main" class="trigger">Apparel</a>
            <div class="sub-level" id="menu-main">
                <ul class="categories column1">
                    <li><span>Jacket</span>
                        <ul class="categories column2">
                            <li data:rel="loadContent.html"><span>Male</span></li>
                            <li><span>Female</span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><span>Shirt</span>
                        <ul class="categories column2">
                            <li>Male</li>
                            <li>Female</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Officer</li>
                    <li data:rel="load-file.htm">Item 1</li>                
                </ul>

            </div>
        </li>
```

CSS

```
    #navigation { left:0px; top:25px; position:relative; width:100%; margin: 0 auto; }
    #navMenu { left:0px; list-style:none outside none; text-align:justify;  }
    .navItem { /*float: left;*/ position:relative; margin-right:5px; width:inherit; display:inline-block; *display:inline;  }
    .trigger { padding:2px 0; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none;  color:#adadad; }
    .trigger:hover, .trigger.hover { color:#332d53; border-bottom:solid 1px #f5d371;}
    .stretch {width: 100%; display: inline-block; *display: inline; zoom: 1; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; }
    #navMenu:first-child .trigger { margin-left:0px; }


    .sub-level { border:1px solid #CCC; width:775px; background-color:#FFFFFF; position:fixed; display:none; height:190px; margin-top:25px; margin-left:-35px; z-index:1001;}
    .extension { width:775px; position:fixed; height:30px; display:none; z-index:1000; /*background-color:#FFF; */}
    .categories { list-style:none outside none; padding-left:0px; height:160px;  font-weight:bold; font-size:10px; color:#adadad; top:0px; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:20px; border-right: solid #DDDDDD 2px;  }
    .categories li { padding:5px; text-transform: uppercase; padding-left:20px;}
    .categories li:hover { /*background-color:#f5d371;*/ color:#332d53; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you maybe give the spacer-div a transparent gif/png as background? Then there might be something for IE to "hit". Just at thought though

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem today, in a case where you have ul > li > a, the ul or anchor must have a background (color suffices) so IE8- doesn't lose focus when hovering an underlying image (it gives a crap on z-indexes). If the background is set only on the anchors, there must be no gap between them. I had a background on the lis and didn't have a clue what's wrong... cursed over IE for a while now...